# Pivot table without knowing row values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, rows

This is my table - `Select ItemName, ItemDescription from MyTable`

I do not know what the values would be in **ItemName** or **ItemDescription**.

Would it be possible to display the data so that **ItemName** would be created as columns and the **ItemDescription** be the row value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires mssql 2008+

```
create table mytable( ItemName varchar(10), ItemDescription varchar(10))

insert mytable values('item 1', 'desc1')
insert mytable values('item 2', 'desc2')
insert mytable values('item 1', 'desc2')

declare @list varchar(2000)
;with cte 
as(
select distinct top 100 percent replace(replace(itemname, ']', ''), '[', '') itemname
from mytable
order by itemname
)
select @list = coalesce(@list + ',' + '['+itemname+']', '['+itemname+']') from cte

declare @sql varchar(4000)
set @sql =
'
select * from
(
select replace(replace(itemname, '']'', ''''), ''['', '''') itemname, ItemDescription, row_number() over (partition by ItemName order by ItemDescription) id from mytable
)  a
PIVOT (MAX([ItemDescription]) FOR [itemname] IN ('+@list+')) AS pvt'

exec (@sql)
```

Result:

```
id  item 1  item 2
1   desc1   desc2
2   desc2   NULL
```